# Trigger.io : Where do i find android apk file created by 'forge run' command?

Tags: trigger.io

Didn't found this in their documentation. Where does apk file generated by "forge run android" is stored? 
I am using Mac osx lion, if it's dependent on this.

Comment: Are you looking to copy & test to a device?  Did you try packaging and self signing it?

Comment: Actually i was interested in looking into content of apk file generated by forge. I will use forge package for it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An APK is created during the `forge run android` command, but it's deleted immediately after installing on the device; if you need to create an APK for use elsewhere or uploading to Google Play, see `forge package android`.

http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.3/releasing.html#android

Comment: This might be the correct link: https://trigger.io/docs/current/recipes/release/release_mobile.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate a keystore file, and run the Package command in forge:

1. Generate a keystore by running: `keytool -genkey -keystore choose-a-name.keystore -alias alias-name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000`. Fill out the information that is asked for. A keystore-file is created.
2. Run the `forge package android` file or run the package tool via a web browser. If run for the first time, it will prompt you to provide the keystore file created in the previous step as well as the password you chose.
3. The location of the apk-file is printed as output.

More information about signing an app can be found on: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html. Also, Trigger's documentation is useful: https://trigger.io/docs/current/recipes/release/release_mobile.html